# Formatting file with awk

Tags: unix, awk, printf

ok so here is the issue on this next file i have so im trying to figure out how to format a file that i created which contains all the information i need but i need to change the output looks so

cat file

```
Jackson D. Bob 0001 book pizza apple 4.00 123as Filer J. Jake 0002 happy apple hat 4.00 124ab Metro K. Jim 0003 kindle pizza grape 4.00 125ac
```

ok so thats like whats in the file and then i need to format the output to something like this

```
 # name           LS   item1  item2     item3   point  ad
 - -------------- ---- ------ --------  ------  -----  -----
 1 Jackson D. Bob 0001 book   pizza     apple   4.00   123as
 2 Filer J. Jake  0002 happy  apple     hat     4.00   124ab
 3 Metro K. Jim   0003 kindle pizza     grape   4.00   125ac
```

Now i have tried a few different things with cat file | awk 'printf{}'
command but it will either just print the first line and fail or will try printing the first name and then each item below it not in this table style

Now item to keep in mind the numbers at the left are generated with a loop and then the  # Name LS are printed into place same with the dashes

Comment: Please clarify the formatting/content of the original file.

Comment: The original file is just a constant flow like if you where to do cat file what i typed is about how it print if that makes sense

Comment: Like what i am curious is if maybe there is a why to pull out each of those lines cause each line is in the correct format that it needs to go into the table its just because its a constant flow! So i wonder if we use while loop with awk -F inside if there is a way to separate the fields and pull each line out?

Comment: Your sample input is all one line. Is your actual input all one line? Are your fields whitespace delimited? Tab delimited? Do you always get all the fields? Can any fields have internal whitespace or just the "name" field? Are the values in the fields "consistent" so they can be used as markers for line-by-line data?

Comment: not sure what whitespace delimited is but the only one that contains white space in the actual name is "name field" like Jackson D. Bob but all the fields continue in the same order throughout the file

Comment: Is it spaces between each "field" or a tab character or something else? How do you expect to be able to "split" the lines? What can you use to tell where one line ends and another begins? What created this horrible output?

Comment: each field is separated by single space but each line ends with 3 digit number followed by 2 letter. thats constant through the board lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is as far as I go

```
$ sed -r 's/[0-9]+[a-z]+ /&\n/g' data_on_a_single_line | column -t

Jackson  D.  Bob   0001  book    pizza  apple  4.00  123as
Filer    J.  Jake  0002  happy   apple  hat    4.00  124ab
Metro    K.  Jim   0003  kindle  pizza  grape  4.00  125ac
```

you can add the magic header and underlines based on field lenghts and perhaps merge the first 3 name fields in `awk`

Comment: now could I output this into a new file? cause if i can do that then i can pipe it into awk and print it with a counter! which is all i need

Comment: also can you explain this statement too just so i know for future use if i have something similar!

Comment: this is to break the long line into records based on your last field characteristic, after that `column -t ` is just for formatting in a tabular form.

Comment: Is the.    data_on_a_single_line      the file or what exactly is that?

Comment: ok i figured it out why i got nothing and it was my syntax and after i fixed it it seemed to work just fine!

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='[0-9]{3}[[:alpha:]]{2}[[:blank:]]*' 'RT{print NR, $0 RT}' file
1 Jackson D. Bob 0001 book pizza apple 4.00 123as
2 Filer J. Jake 0002 happy apple hat 4.00 124ab
3 Metro K. Jim 0003 kindle pizza grape 4.00 125ac
```

Comment: just curious did you just number them yourself? or which part adds the number just want to know so i do need to loop anything if its not needed

Comment: I ran the script as-is on the input you provided and it created the output you see. `NR` is the Number of Records. Try it.

Comment: i keep getting an empty block for some reason would you possible be able to explain this so i can get a grasp of whats happening?

Comment: Either your input isn't as you showed us or you aren't using GNU awk (what does awk --version tell you?) or you copy/pasted the script incorrectly,

Comment: Well it should be as stated because if you go    cat file | awk ' print{$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9}'   it will print the first 9 items which would be the first row however if there are 400 items I do not want to type it out to $400 to be able to print it

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're talking about but you're not providing the info I asked for so - Good luck!